# Get some data using json decode

Tags: php, json, laravel

I have array like this

```
$result = "{
  "datas": "www",
  "data": {
    "id": 1153
  }
}";

$get = json_decode($result);
```

I want to get id in object data. I use `$param = "data->id"` but it doesn't work and I get an error `Undefined property: stdClass::$data->id`
, but if I get datas by using `$param = "datas"`, it works.
to get data I use `return $get->$param` .

How to get id ? sorry for my english.

Comment: `$result` is invalid, double quotes everywhere.

Comment: Fix your `$result`, then use `echo $get->data->id;` to get the id, nothing to spectacular here. https://3v4l.org/GCXU8

Comment: @kerbholz i use this `$result = json_encode(array('datas' => 'www','data' => array('id' => 1153)));`

Comment: json_decode with second param as true returns associative arrays.

Answer (score 3):

After decoding the json will be handled as an array, try to access the property like this:

```
json_decode($result, true)['data']['id']
```

Comment: `['data']['id']` i want this is in inside variable $var . and get data `return $get->$var`

Comment: `['data']['id']` can data->id ?

Comment: do it like this `$data = json_decode($result, true)['data']` then access the id property `$var = $data['id']`

Comment: btw `data->id` is from database . so I declaration in json_decode for get data id.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
$json = '{"datas":"www","data":{"id":1153}}';
$obj = json_decode($json);
echo $obj->datas; //this returns datas
echo '<br/>';
echo $obj->data->id; //this returns data id
```

> Note that `$json` string wrapped with single quotes not double quotes. Individual items wrapped with double quotes.